# withMemoryRebound in Swift 3 is not working for an Objective-C struct pointer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, struct, swift3

I've been trying to interface to an Objective-C library that only exposed the pointer to a C struct array and the count of in that array.

I've used `withMemoryRebound` to the struct and set the capacity as I've seen in other posts here and elsewhere. However, the array I get in Swift has garbage data. As a workaround, I have added an accessor method to the library. But I would really prefer to not modify the library.

Here are the components of a test app that demonstrates the problem followed by the expected results:

Circle.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct {
    float x, y;         /**< Position in pixels. */
    float radius;       /**< Radius in pixels. */
} circle;

@interface CircleGenerator : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic)      size_t              numCircles;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) const circle*  circles;

- (id)init;
// Added as a workaround:
- (void)fetchCircle:(size_t) i circle:(circle *) c;

@end
```

Circle.m:

```
#import "Circle.h"

@interface CircleGenerator ()

@end

const circle myCircles[] = {
    {.x=2467.38184, .y=338.520477, .radius=140.096466},
    {.x=438.689453, .y=1879.302, .radius=116.18354}
};

@implementation CircleGenerator

- (id)init {
    _numCircles = 2;
    _circles = myCircles;
    return self;
}

// Added as a workaround:
- (void)fetchCircle:(size_t) i circle:(circle *) c {
    *c = _circles[i];
}

@end
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let circleGen = CircleGenerator()!

        var circlesPtr = UnsafePointer(circleGen.circles)
        withUnsafePointer(to: &circlesPtr) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: circle.self, capacity: circleGen.numCircles, {
                for i in 0..<circleGen.numCircles {
                    print($0[i])
                }
            })
        }
        print("\nShould be:")
        var nextCircle:circle = circle(x: 0, y: 0, radius: 0)
        for i in 0..<circleGen.numCircles {
            circleGen.fetchCircle(i, circle: &nextCircle)
            print(nextCircle)
        }
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
circle(x: 6.70394638e-38, y: 1.40129846e-45, radius: 2.47778904e+18)
circle(x: 4.59163468e-41, y: 6.7002974e-38, radius: 1.40129846e-45)
```

---

Should be:

```
circle(x: 2467.38184, y: 338.520477, radius: 140.096466)
circle(x: 438.689453, y: 1879.302, radius: 116.18354)
```

Also, `$0.pointee` and `$.pointee.x`, etc. show the incorrect values of the first element.

Do I have a bug, or should I report this to Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circleGen.circles` is already a typed pointer (`UnsafePointer<circle>`), there is no need to use  `withUnsafePointer()`:

```
for i in 0..<circleGen.numCircles {
    let circle = circleGen.circles[i]
    print(circle)
}
```

Output:

```
circle(x: 2467.38184, y: 338.520477, radius: 140.096466)
circle(x: 438.689453, y: 1879.302, radius: 116.18354)
```

Or create a `UnsafeBufferPointer` which is a "array-like" collection:

```
let circles = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: circleGen.circles, count: circleGen.numCircles)
for circle in circles {
    print(circle)
}
```

But if you are curious why your code does not work:
You are rebinding the pointer to the `circlesPtr` variable itself,
not the pointer stored in that variable. 
You would get the correct result with

```
let circlesPtr = UnsafePointer(circleGen.circles)!
circlesPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: circle.self, capacity: circleGen.numCircles, {
    for i in 0..<circleGen.numCircles {
        print($0[i])
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Martin!  Both ways now work, and I'm glad I don't need to rebind in this case.